# How to generate control points for postscripts curveto operator?

Tags: postscript, bezier, spline

I'm looking for a way to render a bunch of connected lines as a nice continuous curve in postscript. It's important that the rendered curve passes through all my points.

`curveto` seems to be the only available way to draw curves, but that function requires bezier control points, which I don't have.

So, is there a way to calculate control points for my points so `curveto` can be used? Preferably in postscript.

For reference, I've previously used [GraphicsPath.addCurve(float[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3t2be9h.aspx) in .NET which does the conversion to  cubic Bézier control points internally before rendering them. I'm looking for something similar in postscript.

(I am able to interpolate the points using a spline function and then render it using lots and lots of individual lines. It looks ok, but is not really a great solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the code example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-2D-Points-wit) ("Draw a Smooth Curve through a Set of 2D Points with Bezier Primitives").

Answer (score 2):

If you interpolate the points using a spline function, then you have some cubic equations for curve pieces. And they could be transformed to Bernstein polynomial basis to find control points of corresponding Bezier curves.

A*t^3+B*t^2+C*t+D = P0*(1-t)^3+P1*3*t*(1-t)^2+P2*3*t^2*(1-t)+P3*t^3

Make some algebra - expand the brackets, equate coefficients of identical powers of t, express P(i) through the cubic equation coefficients A,B,C,D

```
 p0 = D
 p1 = D + C/3
 p2 = D + C * 2/3 + B/3
 p3 = D + C + B + A
```